# SQL Server sort by array

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

My data structure in SQL Server is as follows:

[image]

I have a series of IDs that I want to sort my list based on these IDs.

For example:

my_ids = 3,5

My final table will be shown as below:

[image]

Is this workable? What is your suggestion for this? Thankful

Comment: Please edit your question and share your simple data as text instead of images

Comment: Also tag only one database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the conditional order :

```
Select *
From mytable
Order by case when id in (3,5) then 1 else 2 end
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/x1YubHl6)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can I use both ASC or DESC in sort?

Comment: Yes you can do it

Comment: Adding `id` as a second `order by` criteria would make the sort predictable.